# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\frac{\sqrt{3\cos2x-1}}{\cos x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\dfrac{\sqrt{3\cos2x-1}}{\cos x}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\dfrac{\sqrt{3(1-\tan^2x)-(1+\tan^2x)}}{\sec x\cos x}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sqrt{2-4\tan^2x}\quad dx$$
$$\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sqrt{1-2\tan^2x}\quad dx$$
$$\tan x=t$$
$$\sec^2x=\dfrac{dt}{dx}$$

$$\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{\sqrt{1-2t^2}}{1+t^2}dt$$

$$t=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\dfrac{dt}{d\theta}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{\cos^2\theta}{1+\dfrac{\sin^2\theta}{2}}d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{2\cos^2\theta}{2+\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{2(1-\sin^2\theta)}{2+\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{2}{2+\sin^2\theta}d\theta-\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{2\sin^2\theta+4-4}{2+\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{6}{2+\sin^2\theta}d\theta-\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}2d\theta$$
$$\int_{0}^{\sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}}\dfrac{6\sec^2\theta}{2\sec^2\theta+\tan^2\theta}d\theta-2\sin^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\dfrac{6}{2+3y^2}dy-2\sin^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{6}}\left(\tan^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{3}y}{
\sqrt{2}}\right)_{x=\sqrt{2}}-2\sin^{-1}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\pi-2\tan^{-1}\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: The substitution with $\tan x=t$ is not correct. Please check your computations.

Comment: so what it should be? I checked it, it seems correct to me.

Comment: ok one sec, yeah I did mistake.

Comment: $1 +t^2$ is at the bottom, not at the top. In fact, your life will be much easier if you correct this silly error. By the way, I do these kind things oftentimes. :p

Comment: ok let me try after that, I was wondering if there is any other way of solving it, this is getting quite long

Answer (score 1):

I tried $\sin x=u$, then $\sqrt3u=\sin\theta$, and finally $v=\tan\theta$ to get
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/6}\frac{\sqrt{3\cos2x-1}}{\cos x}dx&=\sqrt2\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sqrt{1-3u^2}}{1-u^2}du\\
&=\sqrt6\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{3-\sin^2\theta}d\theta\\
&=\sqrt6\int_0^{\sqrt3}\frac{dv}{(1+v^2)(3+2v^2)}\\
&=\sqrt6\int_0^{\sqrt3}\left(\frac1{1+v^2}-\frac2{3+2v^2}\right)dv\\
&=\sqrt6\left[\tan^{-1}v-\sqrt{\frac23}\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac23}v\right)\right]_0^{\sqrt3}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac23}\pi-2\tan^{-1}\sqrt2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$3\cos2x-1-=3(1-2\sin^2x)-1$$

Use $\sin x=u$ to find $$I=\int\sqrt2\dfrac{\sqrt{1-3u^2}}{1-u^2}du$$

$$\dfrac{2I}{\sqrt2}=\int\dfrac{(1+u)\sqrt{1-3u^2}}{1-u^2}du+\int\dfrac{\sqrt{1-3u^2}(1-u)}{1-u^2}$$

For the first integral, set $1-u=y$ and $1+u=z$ in the second